# How to keep class scope with LinkedIn Login API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, linkedin-api

I'm making a quick LinkedIn login plugin and I don't know how to keep the JS scope of my class inside the callback method.

The HTML:

```
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="linkedInLogin.linkedInRequest"></script>
```

The JS class:

```
var LinkedInLogin = function() {
    this.init();
};

LinkedInLogin.prototype = {
    init : function() {
        console.log(this);
    },

    linkedInRequest : function() {
        console.log(this);
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields(['firstName', 'lastName', 'email-address', 'picture-url'])
        .result();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var linkedInLogin = new LinkedInLogin();
});
```

The problem is inside my `init` function the scope is the class scope, with access to methods and properties but inside `linkedInRequest` my scope is the window scope. I want it to be the class scope too, so I can split this into multiple methods.

Answer (score 0):

Note that JavaScript doesn't have classes!  You'll only confuse yourself if you try to pretend it does.  The `this` argument is passed according to how a function is *called*, not how it is defined, and evidently the LinkedIn script does not pass it.  You can bypass this by wrapping it with another function that calls it as you wish, or by using the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method.

Your `linkedInLogin` variable is local to the callback you pass to `ready()`, and not visible to the LinkedIn script.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
function LinkedInLogin() { }

LinkedInLogin.prototype = {
    init : function() {
        console.log(this);
    },

    linkedInRequest : function() {
        console.log(this);
        IN.API.Profile("me")
          .fields(['firstName', 'lastName', 'email-address', 'picture-url'])
          .result();
    }
};

var ll = new LinkedInLogin(),
    linkedInRequest = ll.linkedInRequest.bind(ll);

$(document).ready(function() {
    ll.init();
});
```

… and then simply

```
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="linkedInRequest"></script>
```

However, if I may make a suggestion, since you only have one instance your code doesn't really benefit from all this boilerplate.  It could as well be:

```
var LinkedInLogin = {
    init: function() { console.log(this); },
    linkedInRequest: function() {
        console.log(this);
        IN.API.Profile("me")
          .fields(['firstName', 'lastName', 'email-address', 'picture-url'])
          .result();
    }
};

LinkedInLogin.linkedInRequest
  = LinkedInLogin.linkedInRequest.bind(LinkedInLogin);

$(document).ready(function() { LinkedInLogin.init(); });
```

… and then:

```
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="LinkedInLogin.linkedInRequest"></script>
```